# How to program a function in MATLAB that takes two matrices A and B as input and outputs the product matrix A*B?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

**Question**: How do I program a function that takes two matrices A and B as input and outputs the product matrix A*B? Using MATLAB, with stuff like "for" or "while", i.e., loops or conditionals.

**Attempt**:

```
function prodAB=MultiplicoMatrices(A,B)

prod=0;

prodAB=[];

for i=1:length(A)

    for j=1:length(B)

        prod=prod+A(i,j)*B(j,i);

    end

    prodAB(i,j)=prod;

    prod=0;

end

A =

     1     2
     3     4

 B=[5 6 ; 7 8]

B =

     5     6
     7     8
>> prodAB=MultiplicoMatrices([1 2; 3 4],[5 6; 7 8])

prodAB =

     0    19
     0    50
```

Comment: Can someone tell me how to format the code?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  It looks like such.

Comment: it is kinda, why? is it not allowed?

Comment: You should edit the question to show what research you have done. Without that, it will not qualify as a good question.

Comment: (1) What is “Mathlab”?  Do you mean “MATLAB”?   (2) This seems to be enough of a programming question that it belongs on [SO].

Comment: Even before trying to write some code, do you know how to mathematically write a matrix multiplication?

Comment: This question has been crossposted here: [How do I program a function that takes two matrices A and B as input and outputs the product matrix A\*B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836874/how-do-i-program-a-function-that-takes-two-matrices-a-and-b-as-input-and-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

```
function prodAB = MultiplicoMatrices(A,B)
% Initiate output matrix. It will have the same number of rows as A and 
% same number of columns as B
prodAB = zeros(size(A,1),size(B,2));

% Calculate value for every element in output matrix
for row = 1:size(prodAB,1)
    for col = 1:size(prodAB,2)
        
        % Increment using the rows in b or columns in a (they have to be
        % the same anyway)
        for inc = 1:size(B,1)
            prodAB(row,col) = prodAB(row,col) + (A(row,inc)*B(inc,col));     
        end
    end
end
end
```